# Spring @ComponentScan does not scan

Tags: java, spring, bukkit

I have set up a Spring Project (Not Boot). I've done that to use it in a minecraft (paper) plugin. The problem I'm facing now describes as the follwing: I have an `BukkitSpringApplication` class and a `Subserver` class (which is the main class of the bukkit plugin). The `Subserver` class contains an `onEnable()` Method which is called if the plugin starts up. At that point I want to start my Spring Application too better to say: I want to scann my packages for components. I think i've done that correctly, but the only result I'm getting in the console is that there are 5 beans of which 4 are spring related beans and the last one the Application bean (`BukkitSpringApplication`).

Console:

```
[15:35:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [Subserver-bukkit] Enabling Subserver-bukkit v1.0*
[15:35:36] [Server thread/INFO]: 5
[15:35:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [Subserver-bukkit] org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor
[15:35:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [Subserver-bukkit] org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor
[15:35:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [Subserver-bukkit] org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
[15:35:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [Subserver-bukkit] org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
[15:35:36] [Server thread/INFO]: [Subserver-bukkit] bukkitSpringApplication
[15:35:36] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling Subserver-bukkit v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.nebelniek.BukkitConfiguration' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at de.nebelniek.Subserver.onEnable(Subserver.java:22) ~[bukkit-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:370) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:500) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:561) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_17_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:475) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:733) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:353) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1230) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:322) ~[patched_1.17.1.jar:git-Purpur-1418]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[?:?]
```

My `Subserver` class:

```java
public class Subserver extends JavaPlugin {

    private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(BukkitSpringApplication.class);
        System.out.println(context.getBeanDefinitionCount());
        for (String beanName : context.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
        BukkitConfiguration bukkitConfiguration = context.getBean(BukkitConfiguration.class);
        bukkitConfiguration.startMinecraftPlugin(context, this);
        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        context.close();
        context = null;
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "de.nebelniek")
public class BukkitSpringApplication {

}
```

My `BukkitConfiguration` :

```java
package de.nebelniek;

@Getter
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)
public class BukkitConfiguration {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    private final HomeController homeController;
    private final VerifyController verifyController;

    private CredentialManager credentialManager;

    public void startMinecraftPlugin(ApplicationContext context, JavaPlugin plugin) {
        this.eventPublisher.publishEvent(new BukkitPluginEnableEvent(context, plugin));
        this.homeController.setupRoutes();
        this.verifyController.setupRoutes();
    }

    @Setter
    private PaperCommandManager commandManager;

}
```

So do anyone know what I've doen wrong?
Thanks for your help! <3

Comment: Can you please show us your `BukkitConfiguration`? Is it appropriately annotated? We'd need a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, adding to @SotiriosDelimanolis comment, please don't post screenshots. Instead edit your question and copy/paste the stacktrace log as code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Is the `@Configuration` on `BukkitSpringApplication` the one from Spring? Are you sure there's no typo in the package names anywhere?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yea, its the `@Configuration` from Spring. And the package names are the right ones. I've tried to start it via a main-method and it kind of worked - at least the creation of the beans. Thats the weird part I've stumbled over and why im confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it to solve this issue. The problem here is, that spring uses the default `ClassLoader` but, since I'm using bukkit, the classes get loaded by a `PluginClassLoader`.

**So how do I get the `PluginClassLoader`?**

In a class extending `JavaPlugin` you can easily invoke `getClassLoader()` to get the `PluginClassLoader`.

**Now how do I set it to be the one spring is using?**

Just throw this in your `onEnable()` and you'll be good.

```java
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClassLoader());
```

Anyways, thanks for your help.